# What is the highest state in the context of finite state automata?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

I am doing an assignment for my Theory of Computation course. We are writing a function and I am having a hard time understanding what "highest" state means in the following context:

```
dfsa --- a DFSA
f --- from state for regular expression
t --- to state for regular expression
h --- highest state paths from f to t may pass through
```

I understand what $t$ and $f$ mean but, what does $h$ mean?

EDIT: More context:

```
def transition_to_regex(dfsa, f, t, h):
'''(DFSA, int, int, int) -> str
Return regular expression for strings that drive dfsa from state f to state
t with higheset intermediate state h.
States of the DFSA are non-negative integers.
dfsa --- a DFSA
f --- from state for regular expression
t --- to state for regular expression
h --- highest state paths from f to t may pass through
'''
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without a context, but perhaps there is some kind of inductive reasoning going on; in such case we might want to order states as $s_0, s_1, \ldots, s_{n-1}$ (in any fashion) and see what is the highest _index_ of any state on any path from $f$ to $t$. I don't know, I'm only speculating (more context would help).

Comment: @dtldarek I've added more context to what I need to do.

Comment: Well it seems that your states are, under the hood, numbers. Hence, the highest state would be the one that corresponds to the highest number $\ddot\smile$